# Why is the overlay not showing for iPhone app in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, overlay, geometry

I'm trying to follow the overlay instructions provided here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW15+

but the overlay isn't showing. Here's a step by step of what I've done so far:

1.) Added a new View Controller object to the storyboard
2.) Added a Map View object to the new view controller
3.) Went to File, New, New File..., UIViewController subclass, named it "MapViewController", which added three files to my project: MapViewController.h, MapViewController.m, and MapViewController.xib
4.) Then I went to the view controller and defined its class as MapViewController
5.) Then "Control" + Clicked the MKMapView object over to the MapViewController.h which created: "@property (weak, non atomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *MKPolygonView;
6.) I then added the appropriate code to my .h and .m files to reflect the example, which I'll include a copy of below

When I start the iOS simulator the map shows up, but the overlay doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

MapViewController.h :

```
//
//  MapViewController.h
//  GeoShapes
//
//  Created by Template User on 4/1/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet MKMapView *map;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *MKPolygonView;


@end
```

MapViewController.m :

```
//
//  MapViewController.m
//  GeoShapes
//
//  Created by Template User on 4/1/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MapViewController.h"

@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize MKPolygonView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
}
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setMKPolygonView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

    // Define an overlay that covers Colorado.
    CLLocationCoordinate2D  points[4];

    points[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.000512, -109.050116);
    points[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.002371, -102.052066);
    points[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.993076, -102.041981);
    points[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.99892, -109.045267);

    MKPolygon* poly = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:points count:4];
    poly.title = @"Colorado";

    [map addOverlay:poly];
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
    {
        MKPolygonView*    aView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:       (MKPolygon*)overlay];

        aView.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        aView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        aView.lineWidth = 3;

        return aView;
}

    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: In addition to the fix mentioned in the answers: In the xib, check that the map view's delegate outlet is hooked up to the view controller (Ctrl-Click on the map view then drag from delegate outlet to the view controller icon).  Also, why do you have two MKMapView IBOutlets declared in the .h (and one of them is named MKPolygonView which is very strange and confusing)?

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! And thanks to the responses below, which basically say the same thing, I'm just choosing the most descriptive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code bellow in `viewDidUnload` to `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self setMKPolygonView:nil];

// Define an overlay that covers Colorado.
CLLocationCoordinate2D  points[4];

points[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.000512, -109.050116);
points[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.002371, -102.052066);
points[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.993076, -102.041981);
points[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(36.99892, -109.045267);

MKPolygon* poly = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:points count:4];
poly.title = @"Colorado";

[map addOverlay:poly];
```

Comment: Moved it to the viewDidLoad, but overlay is still not showing

Answer (score 1):

I think you've put code into `viewDidUnload` that belongs in `viewDidLoad`.  You're adding an overlay when the view gets unloaded, which is probably not what you intended.